# bit swapping with char type in C

Tags: c, char, bit-manipulation, swap

the data type is char, and the pattern is follow:

source byte: [0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]

destination: [6][7][4][5][2][3][0][1]

for example, if I pass a char, 29 to this function, it will do the swapping and return a char type value, which is 116.

How can I do the swapping?

thank you.

========================

Just wondering if I can do in this way?

```
unsigned char mask = 128;
char num = 0, value1 = 29;
int i, a;

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 6 || i == 7)
    a = 6;
  else
    a = 2;

  if(i < 4)
    num = ((value1 & mask) >> a);
  else
    num = ((value1 & mask) << a);

  result = (result | num);

  if(i<7)
    mask = mask >> 1;
}
```

Comment: Huh? You have a 3 bit value you're rotating? But in a char? With 8 bits? Three doesn't divide into eight cleanly..

Comment: What? His example is `29 = 00011101` and he converts it to `116 = 01110100` by rearranging the bits

Comment: Is this for correcting addresses after doing an in-place FFT/DFT?  It looks familiar...

Comment: Ooooh.. I thought he was doing a base-8 manipulation, not bit rotation of a byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually number my bits the other way -- so that bit 0 is the LSB. Following your numbering scheme:

```
unsigned char src = 29;
unsigned char dst = 0;
dst = (((src & 0x80) >> 6) | // bit 0
       ((src & 0x40) >> 6) | // bit 1
       ((src & 0x20) >> 2) | // bit 2
       ((src & 0x10) >> 2) | // bit 3
       ((src & 0x08) << 2) | // bit 4
       ((src & 0x04) << 2) | // bit 5
       ((src & 0x02) << 6) | // bit 6
       ((src & 0x01) << 6) // bit 7
      );
```

Unless of course, you're numbering them "the right way", but drawing them "backwards" -- then just reverse what I've done above. (Not that I'm trying to start a religious war here...)

Comment: There are obvious ways to make this more efficient. I'm leaving the code above as-is for clarity, optimization is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'd say the numbering of the bits doesn't matter for this problem.

Comment: @jdv - Agreed, since it is symmetrical.

Comment: unsigned char mask = 128; char num = 0, value1 = 29; int i, a;

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) { if((i == 0) || (i == 1) || (i == 6) || (i == 7)) a = 6; else a = 2;

if(i < 4) num = ((value1 & mask) >> a); else num = ((value1 & mask) << a);

mask = mask >> 1; if(i == 7) num = num; else num = (num | num);

Answer (score 4):

or a lookup table

just in case you dont understand that. Here is more detail

For each of the 256 possible inputs work out the answer (by hand)

then do

```
unsigned char answers[256] = {0x00, 0x40,0x21.....};
unsigned char answer = answers[input];
```

I hasten to add that the values I gave are an example - and are certainly not correct

Comment: +1 This operation seems significantly complex that an overhead of 256 bytes may be your best option.

Answer (score 3):

See the "*Reversing bit sequences*" section on [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Also, if you want to do it yourself:

To read the *n*-th bit: `int bit = value & (1 << n);` If the bit is not set, `bit` is 0.

To set the *n*-th bit: `value |= 1 << n;` (value = value OR (1 shifted by n digits))

To clear the *n*-th bit: `value &= ~(1 << n);` (value = value AND NOT (1 shifted by n digits))

Answer (score 1):

First swap the lower four bits with the higher four bits, then swap all adjacent pairs of bits:

```
dst = src;
dst = ((dst & 0xF0) >> 4) | ((dst & 0x0F) << 4);
dst = ((dst & 0xCC) >> 2) | ((dst & 0x33) << 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful:

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious

but it the bit reversal there isn't exactly what you need.  With just a little work you could change the "obvious" algorithm to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate through carry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Rotate_through_carry

So this would work:

```
myByte = myByte << 2 | myByte >> 6;
```

Comment: Easy in assembler, but how would you do that in C ?

Comment: It works for me but I don't know why. Surely shifting right 8 bits yields zero?

Answer (score 0):

```
source byte: [01][23][45][67] to
destination: [67][45][23][01]
```

Implementation:

```
unsigned char shiftit( unsigned char in ) {
  unsigned char out;

  out = (
    (( in & 0xC0 ) >> 6) + /* top 2 to bottom 2 */
    (( in & 0x30 ) >> 2) + /* centre-left 2 to centre-right */
    (( in & 0x0C ) << 2) + /* centre-right 2 to centre-left */
    (( in & 0x03 ) << 6)   /* bottom 2 to top 2 */
  );

  return( out );
}
```

Returns 116 when called `shiftit( 29 )`.